# Find String After Last Dot and Remove Last word which is Starting from Capital letter USing RegEx

Tags: java, regex

```
String myString = "abc.kiransinh.bapu.abc.events.KiranSinhBorasibBapu";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[^.]+(?=[^.]*$)[^Bapu]");
    System.out.println(myString);

    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(myString);

    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        String ResultString = regexMatcher.group();
        ResultString=ResultString.replaceAll("(.)(\\p{Lu})", "$1_$2").toUpperCase();
        System.out.println(ResultString);
    }
```

**Desire Output is: KIRAN_SINH_BORASIAB**

i tried Above code.Want to use only Regex.
though i have used replaceAll method.

Desired Output might be possible using only Regex.
I am new to regex.Any help woud be too much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to match the string you desire:

```
String re = "(?<=\\.)(?=[^.]*$)\\p{Lu}\\p{L}*?(?=\\p{Lu}(?=[^\\p{Lu}]*$))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(re);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yF1pK4/1)

Use `Matcher#find` to get your matched text.

```
Matcher regexMatcher = pattern.matcher( input );

if (regexMatcher.find()) {
   System.out.println( regexMatcher.group() );
}
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
(?<=\.)                   # lookbehind to assert preceding char is DOT
(?=[^.]*$)                # lookahead to assert there is no further DOT in text
\p{Lu}                    # match a unicode uppercase letter
\p{L}*?                   # match 0 or more of unicode letters (non-greedy)
(?=\p{Lu}(?=[^\p{Lu}]*$)) # make sure next char is uppercase letter and further
                          # (?=[^\p{Lu}]*$) makes sure there is no uppercase letter after
```

Comment: I think OP mistakenly presumes `replaceAll` is not about regular expressions, and wants to replace the String by producing the desired output.

Comment: Hmm I further added some more code to show how to use this regex.

Comment: Yes, but I think they want to obtain the desired result if the validation triggers, but without using `replaceAll` for some reason. To be honest think the question is not very clear (not to mention, not particularly useful).